# Opengeo and Ubuntu memory issue

Tags: ubuntu, lidar, boundless-suite

I was working with LiDAR in Opengeo suite while following the Boundless tutorials (http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/tutorial-lidar/)

In my recent post  titled 'LiDAR and Opengeo', I mentioned about the error with PDAL execution. I solved the issue by  editing the 'laz2pg.xml' file and added appropriate port, localhost and password in the xml file.

And now pdal commands can send request to read files. On the terminal, the white cursor blinks for a while and then stopped. At this point  the terminal no longer respond. Here is the error message:

`rblzaman@ubuntu:~/Downloads/tileindex$ pdal pipeline laz2pg.xml
Requested to read 11418635 points
Requested to write 11418635 points
0Killed
rblzaman@ubuntu:~/Downloads/tileindex$`

In the following day, in my same PC (Ubuntu installed on windows 7 via VM player),

it show the following error:

`rblzaman@ubuntu:~/Downloads/tileindex$ pdal pipeline laz2pg.xml
Requested to read 11418635 points
Requested to write 11418635 points
0Caught exception: std::bad_alloc
rblzaman@ubuntu:~/Downloads/tileindex$`

When I typed   'free -m' , it returns,
`rblzaman@ubuntu:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1000        744        256          0         16        233
-/+ buffers/cache:        493        506
Swap:         1020        329        691
rblzaman@ubuntu:~$`

Is this memory issue ? I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on windows 7 using VM player. How to solve this error ?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue...